# Use post ID in functions.php file adminside

Tags: php, functions, id

For a functions I need the post ID in my functions.php file.
I must have the ID if the editpage is active.

What I tried so far

```
<?php
//method 1
global $post;
my_function($post->ID);

//method 2
my_function($post_id);

//method 3
my_function(get_queried_object_id());
?>
```

If I echo $post->ID or $post_id or get_queried_object_id() they give nothing / empty

Who can help me?

Comment: Is your function hooked to a particular action or filter hook? It'll help us a lot if you [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/386983/edit)  to show us more of your code.

Comment: In `functions.php` the query has not happened yet, WordPress hasn't parsed the URL or fetched posts yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on, where you are calling these functions. That is the point, where you enter the var into the function.

First, remove the `global $post` from your functions.php! It makes no sense there! In the functions.php you declare the functions, not call them!

I assume, you call your function in some template. So the functions.php should look like this:

```
function myfunction($post) {
    // $post is now a copy of the $post object, it needs to be passed in the call. See below!

    do_something($post->ID);
}
```

Or you could use the global keyword, to make the $post variable available inside the function:

```
function myFunction() {
    global $post;
    // now you can use $post from the global scope

    do_something($post->ID);
}
```

So, you could use $post globally, using the `global` keyword **inside** the function (second example), or you can pass the $post variable as a function parameter (first example). Both have their pros and cons, e.g. if you pass it as a parameter, PHP copies the $post object for usage inside the function, whereas using global it uses the original. I recommend reading up on PHP scopes. :)

Now you have a correct declaration of the function - you are ready to call it! In your template, or whereever you are, do this:

```
<?php myFunction($post); ?>
```

or

```
<?php myFunction(); ?>
```

depending on which version you decided on. In any case, you'll probably need to do this inside the_loop!